# spring security stop crushed session

Tags: spring, spring-security-ldap

I'm using spring security for the first time and when I thought that I finished I met a problem with the spring security sessions. The scenario is when I log in with a first user and after log in with another user in another machine
if I refresh the first user, the details of the second user are displayed.
It's like the session of the 1st user is crushed by the second user and I don't understand why. There is my spring security configuration:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <sec:http auto-config="true" >
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/jsf/home.xhtml" 
        access="ROLE_ECRITURE, ROLE_LECTURE, ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/jsf/resultTestEligibilite_ADSL.xhtml" 
            access="ROLE_ECRITURE, ROLE_LECTURE, ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/jsf/resultTestEligibilite_SDSL.xhtml" 
            access="ROLE_ECRITURE, ROLE_LECTURE, ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/jsf/resultTestEligibilite_SDSLplus.xhtml" 
            access="ROLE_ECRITURE, ROLE_LECTURE, ROLE_ADMIN" />

        <sec:logout invalidate-session="true" 
            delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" 
            success-handler-ref="customLogoutSuccessHandler"/>

        <sec:form-login login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
            login-page="/index.xhtml" default-target-url="/jsf/home.xhtml"
            authentication-failure-url="/index.xhtml?error=1" />

        <sec:session-management invalid-session-url="/j_spring_security_logout" />
    </sec:http>


    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="false" />
        <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>
                    classpath:/jboss.properties
                </value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="ldapUserSearch"
        class="org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="${ldap.user-search-base}" />
        <constructor-arg index="1" value="${ldap.user-search-filter}" />
        <constructor-arg index="2" ref="contextSource" />
        <property name="searchSubtree" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="contextSource"
        class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
        <constructor-arg value="${ldap.url}" />
        <property name="userDn" value="${ldap.manager-dn}" />
        <property name="password" value="${ldap.manager-password}" />
    </bean>

    <sec:ldap-server
       url="${ldap.url}"    
       manager-dn="${ldap.manager-dn}" 
       manager-password="${ldap.manager-password}" 
       id = "contextSource"
       root="${ldap.root}"/>

    <sec:ldap-user-service id="ldapUserService"
        server-ref="contextSource" 
        group-search-base="${ldap.group-search-base}"
        group-role-attribute="${ldap.group-role-attribute}" 
        group-search-filter="${ldap.group-search-filter}"
        user-search-base="${ldap.user-search-base}" 
        user-search-filter="${ldap.user-search-filter}" />


    <sec:authentication-manager alias="MyManager">
        <sec:ldap-authentication-provider
            user-search-base="${ldap.user-search-base}" 
            user-search-filter="${ldap.user-search-filter}"
            group-search-base="${ldap.group-search-base}" 
            group-search-filter="${ldap.group-search-filter}"
            role-prefix="${ldap.role-prefix}" 
            user-context-mapper-ref="customUserDetailsMapper">
                <sec:password-compare hash="{sha}" >
                    <sec:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"  />
                </sec:password-compare>
            </sec:ldap-authentication-provider>
    </sec:authentication-manager>




    <bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.LdapShaPasswordEncoder" >
        <property name="forceLowerCasePrefix" value="true" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="LdapUserDetailManager"
        class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.LdapUserDetailsManager">
        <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />

        <property name="attributesToRetrieve" >
            <list>
                <value>wsEligXdslFaiUsername</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="customUserDetailsMapper" class="com.axione.eligibilite.ihm.ldap.impl.CustomUserDetailsContextMapper" />
</beans>`enter code here`
```

Thank you in advance of your help, cause I really don't know where this problem comes from.

Comment: Are you really loggin in on a different machine? Or using 2 browsers/tabs on a single machine?

Comment: I tried both. In a different browser and after in a different machine. And earch time the first session is crushed and the first user looses his information and get the information of the second user

Comment: I highly doubt that that really is the case (it should/could be in a single browser). How are you showing this information/testing this?

Comment: Judging from the configuration you are using JSF. Post your index.xhtml and the backing bean.

Comment: I'm connecting from 2 differents computers to test this

Comment: I mean how are you testing the fact that the session is destroyed?

Comment: Don't add your code as an answer, add it as an edit to your question.

Comment: Your controller is a singleton, the `@SessionScoped` is useless as that is a JSF scope, whereas `@Controller` is a spring annotation. Spring knowns nothing about `@SessionScope`. You have 1 instance shared amongst all users... So if you have a header or whatever showing the content of `#{loginBean.name}` that always is the name of the last user that has logged in, the bean is a singleton.